# Special Solver Definition using Google Optimization Tools

Tags: python, solver, cplex

I want to learn something. Can anyone tell me the meaning of following expression:

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

def main():

solver=pywraplp.Solver('TravellingSalesmanProblemMIP', pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)
```

It is used for create a solver, I guess. When is it used? And, if we solve our python model with CPLEX, is there any special correspondence of this expression for cplex? I came across these lines a few times on the internet; I just want to learn.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You guessed correctly. That creates an instance of the `Solver` class with a `name` of 'TravellingSalesmanProblemMIP' and a `problem_type` of `CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING`. You have to create an instance of `Solver` to solve a problem. If you wanted to use CPLEX instead of CBC, you'd replace `CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING` with `CPLEX_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING`. The documentation for this project is [here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/) and the source code (git repo) is [here](https://github.com/google/or-tools). There are many Python examples [here](https://github.com/google/or-tools/tree/master/examples/python).

This project appears to be written in C++ and the Python wrapper is auto-generated from that. The Python-specific documentation seems to be lacking. You will likely need to study the source code to find answers. If that sounds intimidating, you may want to use something else.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer  and you are extremely right python specific documentation is pretty scarce and I have some difficulties about this case.